# How to get system service in composable function?

Tags: android, android-service, android-jetpack-compose

I need to register SensorManager in composable function I use this [`link`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis)  of the android document and want to register SensorManager just like the document registered broadcast receiver but I don't know how to get system service in order to initialize SensorManager.

Comment: If nothing else, `LocalContext.current` is a `Context` that you could use to call `getSystemService()`.

Comment: That's right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : Any> getRequiredService(): T {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    return requireNotNull(context.getSystemService())
}

// usage inside composable

val sensorManager = getRequiredService<SensorManager>()
```

Comment: If you were wondering how to use this in API levels lower than 23 just use `ContextCompat.getSystemService`.